# Pass List of Numbers to Python Script

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a column of numbers to a Python script to then convert into a `numpy` array.

**input.txt**

```
42
42.4
43.5153
44
```

**Bash Code**

```
python script.py ${input}
```

**Python Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import numpy

in = sys.argv[1]

in_out = np.array([float(in)])
print "Inputs:" in_out

sys.exit()
```

**Python Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    in_out = np.array([float(in)])
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 42
```

Comment: What is `in_in` and `${input}`? I presume you need to read the file instead of reading  and parsing the filename as a float

Comment: Please excuse my typo(s). I have edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np


with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    data = np.array([float(line.strip()) for line in input_file])
```

You need to cast all values as float so that numpy is only storing one datatype in the array.

If you want to supply the file as an argument, you can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys


file_name = sys.argv[1]
with open(file_name) as input_file:
    data = np.array([float(line.strip()) for line in input_file])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your `in` variable (which can't be a variable in Python, but we'll go with that) is a string of all values. So you need to split it and apply `float` to each individually:

```
np.array(list(map(float, in.split())))
```

But I'd suggest reading an `input.txt` file directly from Python.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.loadtxt`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

in_out = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=float)
print(in_out)
```

**Output:**

```
[42.     42.4    43.5153 44.    ]
```